# best way to get visibility to class in module

Tags: ruby

Any suggestions for best way to not need to use '::' for use of class in module (as shown below)?

Use import/mixin? It's not a multi-inheritance case though? Just want to simlify the code. Is there a side effect of using import for this case?

```
module Shapes  
    class Circle  
    class RightTriangle  
end

class ShapeUser  
    def go  
        shape1 = Shapes::Circle.new   
        ** prefer to use just shape1 = Circle.new
        ....
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`include` the module:

```
class ShapeUser
  include Shapes

  def go
    shape1 = Circle.new
    # ...
  end
end
```

All that is happening here is you are making the constants `Circle`, `RightTriangle` etc available to the class `ShapeUser`. This is a perfectly reasonable use of `include` :)

Comment: Thank you banister!!  For some reason I couldn't get performance implications out of my head; I think maybe memories of some other languages.

Comment: I wanted to vote you up, but new here, so don't seem to have enough points yet.

Comment: @Gary - Don't forget to click the check mark next to banister's answer to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Note that, just because multiple inheritance is not possible in Ruby—and mix-ins are often touted to allow you to achieve something similar—it doesn't mean that all uses of mix-ins and modules must therefore be for multiple inheritance cases!

This is a wonderful place to use `include`.

Comment: Just one more note on incude -- if you have nested modules and classes the include must be put at the specific level (module or class) where the visibiliy is desired.  Thanks again for the help. Will do on accepting answer; I'll briefly make sure this note makes sense first.

Comment: No problems. Some other neat things you can do with this include defining class methods on modules called `included` and `extended` - they're called when they've been included or extended into another class/module, and they take one argument, which is the place they're headed. You can do some nifty stuff at runtime!